# Bluetooth reconnect issue with Sony WH-1000XM3

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

To reconnect WH-1000XM3 headphones each time I have to do the next steps:

- Go to Ubuntu settings
- Click to headphones in Bluetooth devices
- Click multiple times (5-10 times) the button to connect
  Then loading spinner moves for ~2 seconds. After that headphones, are connected.
  The same issue happens in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.

Does someone know why these headphones don't connect clicking just one time?

Comment: Have you tried completely removing the device and re-pairing it?  Does this behavior only happen with these particular headphones? What happens if you click once and wait?

Comment: > Have you tried completely removing the device and re-pairing it?
Yes
> Does this behavior only happen with these particular headphones?
Yes. With other devices, I don't have this issue. But on another hand this device reconnects well in Android and Windows.
> What happens if you click once and wait? 
Button automatically switches back to off.